# extract specific tag from html output of a python script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a program that should be piped with grep command, the outpu of my program is sth like this:

```
<cite>www.site.com/sdds/ass</cite>A-"><div Class="sa_mc"><div class="sb_tlst"><h3><a href=
```

and so on...

I run a python script:

```
./python.py | grep -Po '(?<=<cite>)([^</cite>])'
```

in order to grep every thing between `cite` tag...

Can you help me?

Comment: You may want to look at `xmlstarlet`.  Parsing XML using regex isn't a fantastic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a proper use of lookaround feature, your lookbehind is fine but lookahead is not. Try this:

```
grep -Po "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)"
```

Ex:

```
 echo '<cite>www.site.com/sdds/ass</cite>A-"><div Class="sa_mc"><div class="sb_tlst"><h3><a href=' | grep -Po "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)"
 www.site.com/sdds/ass
```

Disclaimer: It's a bad practice to parse XML/HTML with regex. You should probably use a parser like xmllint instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sed`. But it's a bad practice to parse XML/HTML with regex.

```
 sed -r 's/^<cite>([^<]*)<\/cite>.*/\1/g' file
```

Output:

```
www.site.com/sdds/ass
```